# How to add a column that contains specific values when criteria is met?

Tags: r, for-loop, tibble

I have a dataframe:

```
tibble{
x = c(1,2,3)
y = c(0,2,4)
}
```

I want to add a NEW variable "z" that will be:

```
z = c("Lower", "Equal", "Higher")
```

I was thinking about using a for loop but I'm not sure if that's the most efficient/correct way.

Answer (score 1):

The new variable in the dataset can be created with `sign` after taking the difference of 'x' and 'y', get the `sign` values, convert it to `factor` with `levels` and corresponding `labels` specified

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
 mutate(z = factor(sign(x - y), levels = c(-1, 0, 1), 
   c('Lower', "Equal", 'Higher')))
```

---

Or an option with `case_when`

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(tmp = x - y,
         z = case_when(tmp >0 ~ 'Higher', tmp < 0 ~ 'Lower',
             TRUE ~ 'Equal'), tmp = NULL)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- tibble(
    x = c(1,2,3),
    y = c(0,2,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
within(df,z <- c("Lower", "Equal", "Higher")[sign(y-x)+2])
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y z     
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     0 Lower
2     2     2 Equal
3     3     4 Higher
```